# AppPackage and browser native messaging host

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging, desktop-bridge

I have Win32 desktop app converted by [Desktop App Converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter).

This app integrates with Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome browsers using extension that communicates with the app using native messaging mechanism.

The problem is that browsers are not able to launch EXE that is a part of App Package. It seems that it's not possible at all.

Is there a solution for this? The only one I can imagine for now is to copy my native messaging host EXE to some folder outside of the package which is not a really good solution because I'll have to also copy heavy DLLs the EXE depends on.

A general advice on how to properly register App Package's native messaging hosts for Chrome/Firefox will also be appreciated.

**Addition #1**. I don't understand why the more info is required for this quite clear case (as for me).

But OK.

1. You must have AppX with nativehost.exe inside it.
2. Install this appx.
3. Modify your native host manifest to point to EXE inside installed Appx. 
   E.g.

   ```
   {
   "allowed_origins": [
       "chrome-extension://.../",
   ],
   "description": "MyApp",
   "name": "somename",
   "path": "C:/Program Files/WindowsApps/MyApp_5.1.30.6486_x86__z4vxg0xscex6e/MyApp/browsernativehost.exe",
   "type": "stdio" }
   ```
4. Launch Chrome with your installed extension. Your port.onDisconnect handler will be called immediately. Error string will be empty.
5. Just copy all the files from installed Appx folder to some "neutral" one. Modify path in manifest.json to point to browsernativehost.exe in that folder. Restart browser. Now extension works fine.

**Addition #2**. Here is the related question:
[Launch app converted by DAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578332/launch-app-converted-by-dac)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: How did you determine "browsers are not able to launch EXE that is a part of App Package"? What did you do that makes you think this?

Comment: Please see addition #1.

Comment: "I have Win32 desktop app",  I guess you mean this app is the native host `nativehost.exe`  for the  Chrome  extensions, but after it is converted to UWP app, it cannot work well? Actually you need the UWP app as the nativehost to work well? If I misunderstand you, please kindly detail that.

Comment: This app includes nativehost.exe, yes. Once my app bundle (it contains many EXEs in it) converted to UWP - browsers are unable to launch nativehost.exe.

Comment: My app is a download manager. I would like to submit it to Windows Store. I used DAC for this. Got appx. Installed it. Performed (manually for now) nativehost registration so it points to nativehost.exe from installed appx. Google Chrome is unable to use such nativehost. It seems it is NOT compatible with Desktop Bridge platform at all. I really do not understand what can be unclear here. Steps above should be enough description to understand  the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev I have the same task with my app (a packaged WFP app). Did you manage to solve the problem or find a decent workaround?

Comment: @Andrey Shcherbakov No, this task was frozen...