# Launch app converted by DAC

Tags: desktop-bridge

1. I've converted my app using `Desktop App Converter`.
2. Installed `appx` from step 1.
3. Launched `cmd.exe` and entered the following command:

   "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyApp_5.1.30.6486_x86__z4vxg0xscex6e\MyApp\myapp.exe"

Got the following error message: `Access is denied`.

1. Why?
2. What is the proper way to programmatically launch DAC converted app including any EXE inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once installed, you can launch the app from the app list in the start menu.

If you need to be able to launch the app from a command box, you will need to declare an appExecutionAlias in the manifest, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#alias

Comment: So, there is no way to launch the app programmatically? I mean some API like `CreateProcess`.

Comment: There are several ways to launch the app programmatically: you can call ShellExecute or CreateProcess on the appExecutionAlias you define, you can call IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication, declare a protocol in the manifest and use that for launch, etc.